# How to use pojo schema to store and retrieve values

Tags: java, android

```
package ModelClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServicesCollection {
    private ArrayList<String>services;
    private ArrayList<String>serviceId;
    private ArrayList<String>duration;

    public ServicesCollection(ArrayList<String> services, ArrayList<String> serviceId, ArrayList<String> duration) {
        this.services = services;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public ServicesCollection(){

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(ArrayList<String> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public void setServiceId(ArrayList<String> serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(ArrayList<String> duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }


}
```

I want to store `firestore` details in `ModelClass`, and I want to retrieve values from that `ModelClass` in different activities. I tried to set values. However, when I try to get the values in different activities, it returns null.

Comment: How are you initializing this class variable in other activities?

Comment: ServicesCollection servicesCollection=new ServicesCollection();

Comment: serviceId.add(id);
                   serviceArray.add(strnName);
                   durationArray.add(intPrice);
                   ServicesCollection servicesCollection=new ServicesCollection();
                   servicesCollection.setServiceId(serviceId);
                   servicesCollection.setServices(serviceArray);   // here i am setting values

Comment: doing `new ServicesCollection()`  will make a new instance of your class, which is why. Look into using static classes (not recommended) or Dagger2.0 injection techniques (recommended)

Comment: I don't know to use dagger 2.0 and all please send any links